# y axis limits with bar graphs

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, axis-labels

I can display a bar graph, but the y axis always starts at zero, which doesn't make sense with this data:

```
y <- data.frame(x=c("a","b","c","d","e","f"), y=c(500,501,502,503,504,505))
ggplot(y, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="bar")
```

Ideally, R would automatically set axis limits like it usually does. If I try to set manually, like as follows, my bars disappear. Any idea why?

```
y <- data.frame(x=c("a","b","c","d","e","f"), y=c(500,501,502,503,504,505))
ggplot(y, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="bar") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(490,510))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `ylim` as follows:

```
y <- data.frame(x=c("a","b","c","d","e","f"), y=c(500,501,502,503,504,505))
ggplot(y, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="bar") + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(490,510))
```

The resulting output is as follows:

[image]